# webpack on traditional html js css bundles?

Tags: javascript, html, css, webpack

I have different web modules that looks like this:

**FileStructure**

```
├───Bundles
│   ├───Bundle1
│   │   └───src
│   │       │   index.html
│   │       │   EntryPoint.js
│   │       │
│   │       └───assets
│   │           ├───css
│   │           │       animate.css
│   │           ├───fonts
│   │           │       Bitter-Bold.otf
│   │           │       Bitter-BoldItalic.otf
│   │           │
│   │           ├───img
│   │           │   │   button-pink.png
│   │           │   │
│   │           │   ├───popup
│   │           │   │       close.png
│   │           │   │
│   │           │   ├───slideshow
│   │           │   │       1.jpg
│   │           │   │       2.jpg
│   │           │   │
│   │           │   └───aaa
│   │           │           1.jpeg
│   │           │
│   │           ├───js
│   │           │       bubble-click.js
│   │           │       bubble.js
│   │           │
│   │           └───video
│   ├───Bundle2
│   │   └───src
│   │       │   index.html
│   │       │   EntryPoint.js
│   │       │
│   │       └───assets
│   │           ├───css
│   │           │       aaa.css
│   │           │
│   │           ├───fonts
│   │           │       Bitter-Bold.otf
│   │           │       Bitter-BoldItalic.otf
│   │           │
│   │           ├───img
│   │           │   ├───a
│   │           │   │       c.png
│   │           │   │
│   │           │   ├───instruction
│   │           │   │       swipe-to-change.gif
│   │           │   │
│   │           │   └───popup
│   │           │           close.png
│   │           │
│   │           ├───js
│   │           │       b.js
```

Bundle1 and Bundle2 are independent of each other, I'm trying to compile them as bundle1.js and bundle2.js and finally include them together in AllBundles.html and I'm using webpack to make sure that the css class names doesn't clash, javascript works independently, etc, each bundle will expose a activate and deactivate method themselves with their own entrypoint.js:

**Entrypoint.js**

```
var mainPage = require('./index.html');

module.exports = {
    activate: function() {
    return "B1 activated";
  },
    deactivate: function() {
    return "B1 deactivated";
  },
}
```

**webpack config:**

```
...
module: {
    preLoaders: [{
      test: /\.jsx$|\.js$/,
      loader: 'eslint-loader',
      include: __dirname + '/src/'
    }],
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
      loader: "babel-loader",
      exclude: [nodeModulesPath]
    }, {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
      loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css!autoprefixer-loader?browsers=last 2 version!sass')
    },{ test: /\.css$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader') },
      { test: /\.jpe?g$|\.gif$|\.png$/i, loader: "file-loader" },
      { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'html-loader' }
    ]
  }
...
```

**Expected Behaviour**

I'm expecting the generated html to convert css classes to have hash code, change css file name, convert javascripts

**Actual Behaviour**

when I run my webpack command, only the img src link gets converted to hashcodes, the link and script tag remains unchanged.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/page-animation.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/animate.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>

but images:

<img class="img-responsive" src="/public/747289b7348be5e879a1c821cae8bffa.png" />
```

what went wrong?